# Looking Up Whether 御 Is Read お or ご

Tags: pronunciation, readings, honorifics, onyomi

Is there a good way to look up whether a `御` prefix is `お` or `ご` for a word? I know there is the Chinese origin versus Japanese origin thing (mentioned [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2111/honorific-prefix-%E3%80%8C%E3%81%94%E3%80%8D-vs-%E3%80%8C%E3%81%8A%E3%80%8D)). But is there a way to look up for a certain word in particular? For example, `御忙しい` and `御自分で`. The dictionaries etc that I've looked at never seem to have it.

Comment: The standard criterion works here: お忙しい and ご自分で.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know of any dictionary or reference book, but since 御 is most often written as お or ご, as appropriate, you could check the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese (BCCWJ, 少納言, http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon) as the proper way of "doing Google counting".

For 忙しい and 自分 the numbers are

> お忙しい 217 results
>   ご忙しい 0 results
>   お自分 8 results, all of which are in fact なお自分, i.e. unrelated to 御自分
>   ご自分 835 results

I guess you already know, but for the record, this confirms that it should be 御{お}忙しい and 御{ご}自分.

Just to show that this also works with words which don't follow the rule "お for native Japanese words, ご for Sino-Japanese words":

> お電話 393 results
>   ご電話 0 results
>   お会計 30 results
>   ご会計 0 results

Another, quick and dirty way would be to check whether your IME already recognizes one or the other as a unit. (My IME knows お忙しい and ご自分, but suggests 語忙しい or 尾自分 and parses the latter ones as ご＋忙しい and お＋自分. Similarly for 電話 and 会計.)