# Why does ゆっくり take the honorific prefix ご?

Tags: honorifics

Is ゆっくり the only mimetic expression that accepts the honorific prefix ご?

And for that matter, why does it take the honorific prefix ご- which is usually meant for 漢語?

Comment: Related: [Honorific prefix 「ご」 vs 「お」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2111/542), [Looking Up Whether 御 is お or ご](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15881/542)

Comment: 明鏡には、`まれに、和語であっても、「ご」が付くものがある。「ごもっとも・ごゆっくり・ごゆるり」`って書いてありますね。　https://sakura-paris.org/dict/%E6%98%8E%E9%8F%A1%E5%9B%BD%E8%AA%9E%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/content/745_738

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of exceptions regarding the usage of お/ご, and, ultimately, you have to learn them individually.

According to a survey by Tanaka (1972) based on the word usage of newspapers, お attaches to a kango roughly 20% of the time, but ご very rarely attaches to a wago (they identified only ごもっとも and ごゆっくり). Even a [long academic article](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/148765785.pdf) dedicated for this topic lists only ごもっとも, ごゆっくり and ごゆるり. ゆるり is mimetic, so ごゆっくり is **not** the only mimetic expression that accepts ご. Still, you can say the number of such words is very small.

Kango that take お tend to be common and daily words such as お風呂, お料理, お財布, お写真 and お掃除. A few words accept both お and ご, and in such cases ご sounds stiffer (e.g. お誕生 vs ご誕生, お返事 vs ご返事). FWIW, I feel ごゆっくり, ごもっとも and ごゆるり also have formal, polite or even a little pompous overtones.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I edited my answer by adding the text inside [] in the 1st paragraph below:

In addition, if one prefers to use a one-words sentence like "Relax!", saying only "ゆっくり” sounds confusing　[because saying only ゆっくり would mean "be careful, do it slowly!", instead of "relax!"]. Maybe ゆっくりどうぞ　could work without a ご　but, at least I wouldn't say so.

So, ご　it is partly to ensure that the person to which ゆっくり　is adressed to feels that he/she hears it in a positive way.

p.s. On the other hand using both ご　and どうぞ　in a sarcastic way, the meaning could also be "You are just sitting there on the sofa and you really should realize yourself that while I am washing the dishes, there are lots of things that you could do, like maybe taking out the rubbish!"