# Meaning of お in 奥さんのお誕生日のプレゼント

Tags: morphology, prefixes

Why does お appear in 「奥さんのお誕生日のプレセント」 if it is not part of the word 「誕生日」?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2111/9831